# Javascript reveal text onclick and then close all on next click

Tags: javascript, onclick

This code allows me to click a link and have a piece of text revealed for each and then if I click the same link, the same text gets hidden again.

```
   function reveal(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'inline')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'inline';   
}
```

But what I want is when I click again for ALL the previously revealed text to be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a common class to all of your hidden text elements, and to hide them you select them all using `document.querySelectorAll(".myClass");`, loop through them and hide each one:

```js
function reveal(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'inline') {
    e.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    var allTexts = document.querySelectorAll(".myHiddenText");
    for (var i = 0, len = allTexts.length; i < len; i++) {
      allTexts[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    e.style.display = 'inline';
  }
}
```

```css
.myHiddenText {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="reveal('Text1');">reveal text 1</a>  <span class="myHiddenText" id="Text1">Hidden text 1</span>

<br/>
<a onclick="reveal('Text2');">reveal text 2</a>  <span class="myHiddenText" id="Text2">Hidden text 2</span>

<br/>
<a onclick="reveal('Text3');">reveal text 3</a>  <span class="myHiddenText" id="Text3">Hidden text 3</span>

<br/>
<a onclick="reveal('Text4');">reveal text 4</a>  <span class="myHiddenText" id="Text4">Hidden text 4</span>
```

Comment: Wow its almost perfect except I want it so that when I reveal one text it shows of course but then when I reveal a second, it should hide the first. At the moment it only hides everything when I try to hide any single one. Its certainly better than before though.